# router/modems capable of capturing requests

Tags: tls, windows, http, router

Are there any routers that can capture http or https requests?

Windows UWP apps are able to bypass proxy settings, failing MITM proxy or Charles like applications to capture their requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Yup. "Transparent" proxies do that.

A proxy need not be "explicit". It can also be a "transparent" proxy if it is the gateway used by the client. And then do just the same things an explicit proxy can do. (If the explicit proxy couldn't break HTTPS, then neither can the transparent proxy. If the explicit proxy could break HTTPS, then also can the transparent proxy.)

If for example you use a Sophos firewall in your business the "transparent"/"explicit" proxy thing is a switch you can toggle. See: https://community.sophos.com/kb/en-us/115865